# Google TV on Android device

Tags: google-tv

We have developed a new OTT Streaming STB build on an Android platform.  How do I get it to operate the Google TV system so that the Apps built for GTV will load and run correctly?

Please note: I am NOT looking for advice on how to get an app onto the GTV platform - what I need is to get the Google TV platform on my STB.

Thanx 
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Google TV is not open source. It is built in a different way to core Android, you can't just add it to your build. Nearly anything built for Google TV will work on other Android devices such as yours. The Google Play device filtering is your real problem.